# OPC UA data rate

Tags: opc-ua

Is there a data rate limit for OPC UA?  I am currently using OPC UA tunneller to transfer data and looks like it is limited to 10 Hz.  Is this a setting that can be changed?

Thanks
Shashi

Comment: Data transfer between server and device, or between server and client? If the former -- see answer by Kevin, if the latter you send configuration from the client requesting given intervals.

Answer (score 1):

The limit is entirely up to the configuration of the OPC UA server you're connected to.

In this case, since you're using a tunneler, you may need to check configuration of the server *behind* the tunneler in addition to the tunneler itself.